# SignalR and Groups

Tags: c#, signalr

Is there a way to get the Caller Group?

To round this I created a **Caller.Group** when the client join the Chat.
And when sending a message, I'm doing this:

```
var clients = Hub.GetClients<ChatHub>();
clients[Caller.group].newMessage(String.Format("({0}) <b>{1}</b>: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"), Caller.Name, message));
clients.isAlive();
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: Is this code inside the hub? If yes, why are you calling GetClients? Also this is an old version of SignalR, you should upgrade.

Comment: Is there any sample built with the new version?

Comment: Yes, in the documentation. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs